# Passing a FD to an unnamed pipe over DBus using Vala

Tags: dbus, vala

I'm trying to send a large block of data between applications by sending a control message over DBus from one to the other requesting a Unix file descriptor. I have it so that the client can request this, the server creates a DBus message that includes a `UnixFDList`, and the client receives a reply message but it doesn't contain anything. On the server side in Vala the `DBusConnection` object is setup using `register_object`, unfortunately the Vapi hides the `DBusInterfaceVTable` parameter that all the C examples use that would let me specify a delegate for method calls. I've tried to use `register_object_with_closures` instead but I can't seem to get that to work and the `Closure` object in Vala is woefully undocumented.

It seems to me that I need one of these methods in order to receive the message from the `DBusMethodInvocation` object that you get from a call to the `DBusInterfaceMethodCallFunc` delegate, with that you can create a reply message. Is there a way to either specify a closure class that works with `register_object_with_closures`, or a way to specify a `DBusInterfaceVTable` object as part of the service data?

I know that one option is to just create the service in C, but I'd rather figure out and understand how this works in Vala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vala uses UnixFDList internally for methods that contain a parameter of type GLib.UnixInputStream, GLib.UnixOutputStream, GLib.Socket, or GLib.FileDescriptorBased.

Example:

```
[DBus(name="eu.tiliado.Nuvola")]
public interface MasterDbusIfce: GLib.Object {
    public abstract void get_connection(
        string app_id,
        string dbus_id,
        out GLib.Socket? socket,
        out string? token) throws GLib.Error;
}
```

Comment: There is an example using UnixInputStream in the Vala test suite. It it [tests/dbus/filedescriptor.test](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/tree/tests/dbus/filedescriptor.test)

Comment: The answer and comment provided by @AlThomas got me what I needed. I hadn't thought to look in a tests folder for examples. Thanks.